# How can I add alarm type and sound in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to add alarm, and I want to add custom sound and add alarm type to audio. I tried but not getting the answer. Can any one help me out please ?

```
func createReminder() {
    let calander = Calendar.current
    let warmane = calander.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 1, to: Date())

    let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: self.eventStore)
    reminder.title = "Go to the store and buy milk"
    reminder.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()

    let date = warmane
    let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: date!)

    reminder.addAlarm(alarm)

    do {
        try eventStore.save(reminder,
            commit: true)

    } catch let error {
            print("Reminder failed with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Notification Tutorial"
    content.subtitle = "from ioscreator.com"
    content.body = " Notification triggered"
    //Default sound
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    //Play custom sound
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named:UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "123.mp3"))

------
```

Comment: can I play this notification for long time ?

Comment: The system sound facility plays custom alert sounds, so they must be in one of the following audio data formats:


Linear PCM


MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)

µLaw

aLaw

You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Sound files must be less than 30 seconds in length. If the sound file is longer than 30 seconds, the system plays the default sound instead.


https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound